# Python combination generation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

*I am new to programming and to Python. Not sure how to proceed to achieve this (explained below) problem, hence the question.*

I have n number of lists, each containing 1 or more items. I want to have a new list with all possible combinations, which uses one item from each list once, and always.

Example:

```
list_1 = ['1','2','3']
list_2 = ['2','5','7']
list_3 = ['9','9','8']
```

Result would be: `['129', '129', '128', '159', '159', '158', '179', '179', '178', '229', '229', '228', '259',  '259', '258', '329', '329', '328', '359', '359','358', '379', '379', '378']`

Example here has 3 lists each with 3 items but there can be any n number of lists each containing any m number of elements (so not all lists need to have same number of elements).

All elements of lists are strings and output list also contains strings.

What should I do?

I looked at itertools.combinations but I have no idea as to how to employ it for this task.

Comment: This is a generic programming task. It's worth googling it yourself before adding another question to the 2,889,573 previous questions here on this task.

Comment: @Marcin: why bother searching? Friendly SO folks are always there for your service.

Comment: @thg435 Why bother learning anything about programming when friendly SO folks will write your code and do your research for you?

Comment: @Marcin: why bother teaching people to learn? The less they (amateurs) know, the more valuable we (professionals) get.

Comment: Excuse me for interrupting on my own question's kindergarden section. If @Marcin had not lost his candy and was not in a bad mood because of his daddy not getting him what toy he wants, he would have payed attention and realised that I actually did my research but due to my newbie status to CS, I do not even know what to look for; And yet with my limited ability I went as far as finding "itertools' combinations" and I did not ask for any code but as to explanation for what to do. I am not getting paid here for this and I had no intention whatsoever to use anyone but to genuinely learn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here:

```
>>> list_1 = ['1','2','3']
>>> list_2 = ['2','5','7']
>>> list_3 = ['9','9','8']
>>> from itertools import product
>>> ["".join(x) for x in product(list_1,list_2,list_3)]
['129', '129', '128', '159', '159', '158', '179', '179', '178', '229', '229', '228', '259', '259', '258', '279', '279', '278', '329', '329', '328', '359', '359', '358', '379', '379', '378']
```

Comment: Dear @AshwiniChaudhary, once again you're helpful solution has helped. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil once again, I am glad that helped. :)

Comment: @Phil: [a more terse code](http://ideone.com/MM6pml): `print map("".join, itertools.product(*["123", "257", "998"]))` it is not recommended (don't use it) but it might be useful to decipher it for educational purposes (its understanding requires to know: functions are first-class citizens in Python, "star"-syntax for providing function arguments, strings are sequences)

Answer (score 6):

use a list comprehension:

```
result = ["%s%s%s" % (i,j,k) for i in list_1 for j in list_2 for k in list_3]
```

or use `itertools`:

```
product = itertools.product(list_1, list_2, list_3)
result = [''.join(p) for p in product]
```

Comment: Thank you @mata! First solution is not that nice since if I have more than 3 lists it would be bit hard to type. ;-)But second one is excellent.